# Fetch one Mysql row at a time in PHP Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have around 10000 records in a mysql table which has id, info and ip columns. ip columns are empty. I want to display one row at a time whenever the page refreshes. For every row displayed i want to store the IP of the client refreshing the page. So whenever the page is refreshed from that IP it displays same info.

I hope i explained it well. How can I make sure that it displays correct row everytime page is refreshed and i don't make extra mysql queries.

Currently I am fetching up all the rows every time person opens the page and then filtering it but I know this is not efficient. Please help

Comment: Why can't you apply the filter in SQL ? Show your code and how you're trying to do it right now.

Comment: You know that there are more than 10,000 possible IP addresses right? Is there are reason to persist this in a database at all, or is the intent to always show the same record to each IP address across session boundaries? What happens on shared IP addresses or proxy IP's?

Comment: Are you using Doctrine? You can select an entry by id, save the IP into it and save it using the ORM.

Comment: @MikeBrant yeah you have a good point, but the main intent is just to show the same info for same ip

Comment: @Hammerstein not sure how to do that! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope understand you. So, you want show the same row to a IP that it already saved:

```
// Controller...
$ip = $container->get('request')->getClientIp(); // The ip

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); // Get the Entity Manager

// First check if the ip has assigned a record
$record = $em->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Records')
    ->findOneByIp( $ip );

if( !$record ){ // There isn't a IP assigned
    $record = $em->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Records')
               ->findOneBy( array('ip' => null) ); // Get other record to assign
    $record->setIp( $ip );
    $em->flush(); // Save the ip
}

return new Response('Record info: ' . $record->getInfo() );
```

The first time you get a record doesn't used, after you get the same record for your IP.

Comment: this works on my local network but when i put it on production, it shows same info for every different IP. Why is that so?

Comment: I don't know, the code is fine and my answer too :S. It checks if a IP exists and get the record, otherwise gets other... Probably you haven't exported the database correctly. Can you do debug?

Comment: yeah you are right actually your code is fine. I dont know how to debug on Production. The prod.log on my symfony website does not show up my log messages!..I feel its caching the result maybe.

Comment: To debug I use XDebug. I suggest you configure it and use it in your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Use the iterate() method together with batch processing.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html

If you need only a subset of the records, you can use  [setFirstResult($num) and setMaxResults($num)](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html).